# How to order by 2 columns combining COALESCE?

Tags: sql, coalesce, sql-order-by

I have a question about ordering a SQL table. And I can't find a solution on stack or google. My table "Score" seems as follows:

```
Name    Total   Tries  Game1  Game2  Game3
------------------------------------------
Sam     65      61     10     31     24             
Tom             55     11            30
Jim     65      58     9      34     22 
Dan     62      52     10     30     22
```

Note: "Total" column is COUNT(Game1 + Game2 + Game3).

As you can see the Total record of Tom is empty, because Tom didn't play Game2.

I want to order my table as follows (highest-lowest priority):

1. Empty cells (at the bottom of the table)
2. Total (ASC)
3. Tries (ASC)

So my table has to look like:

```
Name    Total   Tries  Game1  Game2  Game3
------------------------------------------
Dan     62      52     10     30     22
Jim     65      58     9      34     22 
Sam     65      61     10     31     24             
Tom             55     11            30
```

Which SQL query do I have to use?

This is what I have on this moment, but it will not sort on "Tries":

```
SELECT name, Game1+Game2+Game3 AS Total, Game1, Game2, Game3, Tries
FROM Score 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Tries or Game1 or Game2 or Game3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, 
         COALESCE(Game1,0) + COALESCE(Game2,1) + COALESCE(Game3,2) ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have `NULL` instead of *empty* in `Total` based on the `CASE` statement in your `order by`. Try this `Order by`

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(Total,99999999999) ASC,Tries ASC
```

`99999999999` will make the `NULL` values to sort at the end and the other records will be ordered in ascending order

or

```
ORDER BY case when Total is null then 0 else 1 end desc,Total ASC,Tries ASC
```