# How to display a date before today but my query is for all dates >=CURDATE(), from the same column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Mysql, Pdo, Apache, InnoDB, php 5.4.16.
I need to display events >=CURDATE(). The events could have a duration of 1 day (`tipo_id`=1) or more (`tipo_id`=4). Each event has a date I stored in `data_evento` column as start date. For events having a duration of more than one day I use a `fine_data_evento` column where I stored the end date. Because not all the events have an end date I set `fine_data_evento` as NULL. So I have no problem to display every kind of event starting from today with single date or a "from-to" range of date. For example:

```
Title:Event 01
Date: 12 September 2019
========================
Title:Event 02
Date: From 12/09/2019 to 10/10/2019
========================
Title:Event 03
Date: 13 September 2019
```

The problem is when I try to display `Event 02` the day after (13/09) its starting date (12/09 in the example), as SQL condition is `data_evento`>=CURDATE().

So the question is: how to continue to display events which starts before today and ends some days later, where all the others events start from today?

Maybe Do i need some if in SQL? I red other posts but I could not find an answer. So I can't understand which is a way to work well. I know it is simple but I can't. Thank you.

On the following I have some code.

tutti_eventi.php

```
....
$sql = 'SELECT `id_evento`,`titolo_evento`, `desc_evento`,`data_evento`,`fine_data_evento`, `nome_image`, `nome_categoria`,`comune_nome`,`nome_provincia`,`tipo_id` FROM `eventi`, `images`,`categoria`,`comuni`,`provincia`
              WHERE
              `id_image`=`id_img`
              AND
              `id_categoria`=`cat_id`
              AND
              `id_comune`=`com_id`
              AND
              `id_provincia`=`id_prov`
              AND
              `tipo_id` in (1,4)
              AND
              `data_evento` >= CURDATE()
              ORDER BY
              `data_evento` ASC';
 ....
```

tutti_eventi.html.php

```
 ....
 while ($evento = $eventi->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            ....
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="padding-top:5px;">

                              <?php

                              if (isset($evento['fine_data_evento'])) {

                                $tipo=$evento['tipo_id'];

                                if ($tipo = 4) {

                                echo '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                          <span class="glyphicon-class">';

                                            echo '<span>Dal ';
                                              Setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
                                              $date3= new DateTime($evento['data_evento']);
                                              echo $date3->format('d/m/Y');
                                            echo '</span>';
                                            echo '<span> al ';
                                              Setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
                                              $date4= new DateTime($evento['fine_data_evento']);
                                              echo $date4->format('d/m/Y');
                                            echo '</span>';

                                          echo '</span></p>';
                                        }


                                } else {

                                  echo '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            <span class="glyphicon-class">';

                                              echo '<span>';
                                                Setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
                                                $date= new DateTime($evento['data_evento']);
                                                echo $date->format('l');
                                              echo '</span><br>';
                                              echo '<span>';
                                                Setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
                                                $date1= new DateTime($evento['data_evento']);
                                                echo $date1->format('d F Y');
                                              echo '</span>';
                                            echo '</span><br>';

                                              echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                    <span class="glyphicon-class">';
                                                        $date2= new DateTime($evento['data_evento']);
                                                        echo $date2->format('H'.':'.'i');

                                                    echo '</span></p>';

                                }

                                echo '</div>';

                              echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">'.$evento['desc_evento'].'</div>';

                      echo '</div>';

                  }
                            ?>
```

Thanks to @GMB in particular I am very close to the solution. I added `COALESCE(fine_data_evento, data_evento) >= CURDATE()` in my SQL query. But I need to `ORDER BY ASC`. When I use `DESC` it works fine: `Event 2` is displayed and Events are displayed starting by the last date on the top of the page, while `Event 2` is the first at the bottom. When I use `ASC` instead `Event 2` can't display and the events are correctly displayed starting by today on the top. Watch at the new query:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT `id_evento`, `titolo_evento`, `desc_evento`, `data_evento`, `fine_data_evento`, `nome_image`, `nome_categoria`, `comune_nome`, `nome_provincia`, `tipo_id` FROM `eventi`,  `images`, `categoria`, `comuni`, `provincia`
                  WHERE
                  `id_image`=`id_img`
                  AND
                  `id_categoria`=`cat_id`
                  AND
                  `id_comune`=`com_id`
                  AND
                  `id_provincia`=`id_prov`
                  AND
                  `tipo_id` in (1,4)
                  AND
                  COALESCE(`fine_data_evento`, `data_evento`) >= CURDATE()
                  ORDER BY `data_evento` ASC';
```

And the following is the solution. I red at this post:

[[How to order by 2 columns combining COALESCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950146/how-to-order-by-2-columns-combining-coalesce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950146/how-to-order-by-2-columns-combining-coalesce)

The solution is to add:

`COALESCE(fine_data_evento, data_evento) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY COALESCE (fine_data_evento) ASC, data_evento ASC`

It works: the `Event 2` is placed at the bottom of the page when its start date is before today, while events with `null` end date are sorted by today on the top of the page.

Thank you to all

Comment: Share your table schema.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know this doesn't help, but...PHP 5.4? Don't use PHP 5.4. Relevant - https://youtu.be/wCZ5TJCBWMg?t=2376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you could phrase the condition as:

```
( fine_data_evento IS NULL AND data_evento >= CURDATE() )
OR (fine_data_evento >= CURDATE() AND data_evento <= CURDATE() )
```

This means: if there is no end date, then the start date must be greater or equal than today. If there is an end date, then it must be greater or equal than today, while the start_date must be less or equal than today.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/faWFcr2YG4oPNRz5LoY9Df/4)**:

Given the following sample data:

```
| title   | data_evento | fine_data_evento |
| ------- | ----------- | ---------------- |
| Event 1 | 2019-09-11  |                  |
| Event 2 | 2019-09-10  | 2019-10-10       |
| Event 3 | 2019-09-13  |                  |
| Event 4 | 2019-09-01  |                  |
| Event 5 | 2019-09-01  | 2019-09-10       |
| Event 6 | 2019-10-01  | 2019-10-10       |
```

Current date is `'2019-09-11'`, and the query returns:

```
| title   | data_evento | fine_data_evento |
| ------- | ----------- | ---------------- |
| Event 1 | 2019-09-11  |                  |
| Event 2 | 2019-09-10  | 2019-10-10       |
| Event 3 | 2019-09-13  |                  |
```

Comment: Hello GMB, thank you. I tried your solution but it can't work for me. First version can't display `event 02` when its start date is set before today. The second version make all events displaying with the same title `event 02`. I dont know why

Comment: @datone: I added a db fiddle for your reference. As far as I understand your question, both queries seem to return the expected results.

Comment: Actually I need: if there is no end date, then the start date must be greater or equal than `CURDATE()`[this is ok]. If there is an end date, then it must be `>=CURDATE()` [because the event needs to be published even if the last day is equal to the current day]  and the start date COULD be minor, equal or greater than CURDATE. If minor the event must be displayed while the other events with start date>=CURDATE(). I'm trying to translate this.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the demo. It's the same for me. But what if you try to set `data_evento` of `Event 2` on `2019-09-10`? Event 2 can't be displayed. I know maybe I have some trouble to explain, sorry. My problem is when the start date of Event 2 is before current date.

Comment: @datone: ok, I updated my answer again. If think that, if there is a end date greater or equal than today, you want a start date that is less *or equal* than today. If in that case you do want only start dates *strictly* less than today, just change the last comparison from `data_evento <= CURDATE()` to `data_evento < CURDATE()`.

Comment: I made some tests and you were right: it works, but only if I delete the last condition of my query: `ORDER BY data_evento ASC`, it doesn't work with. How can I order my events starting from today at the top of the page, thanks

Comment: maybe change the order by from `ASC` to `DESC`?

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes, when I change to DESC it works well and `Event 2` is displayed. But I need ASC, and when I use it `Event 2` can't be displayed. There is a reason for sure, but I can't know it